Issue in Ethernet Driver(intel ethernet controller i225-v )
I was updating the device from armory crate(MB Rog strix asus Z690-e wifi ), but when I started the update, the internet disconnected check device manager and intel ethernet controller i225-v error (Windows is still setting up the class configuration for this device. (Code 56)), but my Wifi working good.
Try to reset net work as comment in (CMD) or in sittings, uninstall driver, download driver again but issue still. Open BIOS but nothing to do it.
How to solve issue ?

If did all things like (Try to reset net work as comment in (CMD) or in sittings, uninstall driver, download driver again) but issue still, just restore point then check windows update drivers, after install all new version update your BIOS.
The problem is the driver version is lower than the BIOS and for this reason it became an error due to their incompatibility.
